# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<CustomerTransactionDetail>'

Tags: list, flutter, dynamic

```
customerDetailGet['customer_transaction_detail']
```

receive list of array
how assign list of array to  List of CustomerTransactionDetail which is model

full code

actually using Provider. I have model of Customer Transaction Detail so i want to assign new receive array of list also add in previous list of CustomerTransactionDetail
but error

```
var url = Uri.https(BaseUrl.apiBaseUrl,
          BaseUrl.apiBaseUrlSecond + 'add_customer.php', {});
      Map object = {
        "c_name": nameController.text,
        "c_mobile": mobileController.text,
        "c_address": addressController.text,
        "login_id": Constants.loginId,
      };
      var source = await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode(object));
      if (source.statusCode == 200) {
        if (jsonDecode(source.body)["status"] == 200) {
          var message = jsonDecode(source.body)["result"]["message"];
          var customerDetailGet =
              jsonDecode(source.body)["result"]["customer_detail"];
          var customerDetail = CustomerDetail(
            accountType: customerDetailGet['account_type'],
            address: customerDetailGet['address'],
            conversationNo: customerDetailGet['conversation_no'],
            currentBalance: customerDetailGet['current_balance'],
            customerTransactionDetail: customerDetailGet['customer_transaction_detail'], // error line
            id: customerDetailGet['id'],
            mobile: customerDetailGet['mobile'],
            name: customerDetailGet['name'],
            status: customerDetailGet['status'],
          );
          int debitBalance = jsonDecode(source.body)["result"]
              ["credit_debit_balance"]["debit_balance"];
          int creditBalance = jsonDecode(source.body)["result"]
              ["credit_debit_balance"]["credit_balance"];
          Provider.of<CustomerAndTransactionClassProvider>(context,
                  listen: false)
              .addCustomer(customerDetail, debitBalance, creditBalance);
          setState(() {
            responseResult = message;
            isLoadding = false;
          });
          Navigator.pop(context);
        } else if (jsonDecode(source.body)["status"] == 202) {
          setState(() {
            responseResult = jsonDecode(source.body)["result"]["message"];
            isLoadding = false;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            responseResult = "sorry try again";
            isLoadding = false;
          });
        }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the type of the variable `customerDetailGet`.
If you don't, Dart assumes that it's a `dynamic` and may be unable to process it the way you want (this causes the exception you're getting).

The easiest way to specify the type is to write:

```dart
List<CustomerTransactionDetail> customerDetailGet = List<CustomerTransactionDetail>.from(
  jsonDecode(source.body)["result"]["customer_detail"]
);
```

However, this may fail if `CustomerTransactionDetail` is not a subtype of one of the basic types.
Therefore, you may have to create a new list and instantiate all the values:

```dart
List<CustomerTransactionDetail> customerDetailGet = List<CustomerTransactionDetail>.from(
  jsonDecode(source.body)["result"]["customer_detail"].map(
    (customerDetail) => CustomerTransactionDetail.fromJson(customerDetail)
  )
);
```

In this case, you will have to implement the [factory constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors) `CustomerTransactionDetail.fromJson`.